# Implementing a Finite State machine in C

Tags: c, project, state-machine

I have been writing a code that either accepts or rejects a string of input symbols as part of a specified language. And I have written code for the first language but it doesn't accept the right thing and i was wondering if any one could give me a hint as to where i went wrong. thanks

Question: Why wont the language be accepted or rejected correctly?

Thanks

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static final char initial_state = '0';
static final char 0 = '0';
static final char 1 = '1';
static final char 2 = '2';
static final char 3 = '3';

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int x;
  char current_state, next_state, initial_state;
  current_state = initial_state;

  printf("Enter a string of characters: ");
  while(scanf("%d", &x)!=EOF){
     switch(current_state){
      case 0: /*initial state*/
       switch(current_state){
       case'0':next_state=1; break;
       case'1':next_state=0; break;
       }
       break;
     case 1: /*Last input was 0*/
      switch(current_state){
      case'0':next_state=1; break;
      case'1':next_state=2; break;
      }
      break;
     case 2: /*Last input was 1*/
      switch(current_state){
      case'0':next_state=3; break;
      case'1':next_state=0; break;
      }
      break;
     case 3: /*Last input was 0*/
      switch(current_state){
      case'0':next_state=3; break;
      case'1':next_state=3; break;
      }
      break;
     }
     current_state=next_state;
    }
  if((current_state==next_state)){
    printf("Language 1 accepts");
  }else if((current_state!=next_state)){
    printf("Language 1 rejects");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: An English description of 'Language1' would be most helpful in diagnosing why the Code does not match the Language

Comment: final in c? when did that get there? I've been playing with SQL in recent years instead :)

Comment: Language one is defined by accepting 010 and to get the the accepted state the last character can either be a 0 or a 1.

Comment: @Poodlehat I'm not too sure what you are seeing, could you be more specific please. Thank you

Comment: Does this code compile? With a variable named 0?

Comment: Do you mean for your program to work with `010` or `0 1 0`?  Using `sprintf` your loop would only run once with the former.

Comment: @BrianNickel the program should accept at 010.

Comment: In that case, you should not be using `scanf` but instead `getchar`.

Comment: Okay so if i put while(( c=read()) !EOF) would that be a better choice to use instead of the scanf?

Comment: I don't think you can use `read` like that. I'm pretty sure you have to use `getchar`.  I suggest cracking open a book.

Comment: i didnt think so thats what one of my class mates suggested but i believe your right with using getchar it seems most logic

Comment: What I am saying is that as far as I knew, `static final char initial_state = '0';` looks a lot more like a Java construct than C - when did C get "final" as a keyword (and my undertone is that I have not seen any proof that it actually has)

Comment: C++11 is just getting it as a keyword, and there woudn't be any good reason to use it with a primitive. My guess is you are using a relatively new C++ compiler and aren't compiling your code as C at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `initial_state` twice, and the local one is winning the "scope war." So in your code, every time you think you're referring to this `initial_state`:

```
static final char initial_state = '0';
```

you're actually referring to this initial state:

```
char current_state, next_state, initial_state;  // this last guy here
```

Additionally, you're doing some numerics and some characters. You want all characters since you're taking input from the keyboard. Any place that you define a state as a 1 or a 0, put single quotes around it so it's a `'1'` or a `'0'`.

Then, take out the code that redefines `1 = '1'` for all the states; I do believe you're asking the program to redefine the number 0x1 to mean the number 0x41 -- that's crazy.

Here's the final result (badly formatted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char initial_state = '0';
static const char accepting_state = '3';
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int x;
  char current_state;

  current_state = initial_state;
  printf("Enter a series of characters (0 or 1)\n");
  printf("Press <ctrl-d> to finish.\n");
  printf("> ");
  while(scanf("%d", &x)!=EOF){
     x += '0';
         switch(current_state){
      case '0': /*initial state*/
       switch(x){
       case'0':current_state='1'; break;
       case'1':current_state='0'; break;
       default: goto fail;
       }
       break;
     case '1': /*Last input was 0*/
      switch(x){
      case'0':current_state='1'; break;
      case'1':current_state='2'; break;
      default: goto fail;
      }
      break;
     case '2': /*Last input was 1*/
      switch(x){
      case'0':current_state='3'; break;
      case'1':current_state='0'; break;
      default: goto fail;
      }
      break;
     case '3': /*Last input was 0*/
      switch(x){
      case'0':current_state='3'; break;
      case'1':current_state='3'; break;
      default: goto fail;
      }
      break;
     default: goto fail;
     }
     printf("> ");
  }

  if (current_state == accepting_state) {
    printf("Language accepts!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Language rejects.\n");
  }
  return 0;

fail:
  printf("Invalid input\n");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: oh so is there one that should be used over the other, b/c i shouldnt have to call it twice correct?

Comment: the static final char 0 = '0'; should be changed to static final char 0 ; ? If im understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting initial state as a character zero and not a numeric zero.
Try this instead:

```
static final char initial_state = 0;
```

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense that you.! I will try that.

Comment: That said, that definition of `initial_state` is ignored as it is also defined (but not set) in `main`.

Comment: No, you're accepting characters, so you need to go through the program and make all of them character zero, i.e. `'0'` and `'1'`

Comment: so should i also set it in main as well, even though I have placed it as a char ?

Comment: @RobertMartin in which part do you suggest making them characters, b/c in the case'0' i have defined then as characters, should the part for example next_state=0,or 1 should i change that to next_state='1' or '0'

Comment: He's actually not accepting characters since he's using `scanf("%d")`.  All the variables should be ints or he should be using `getchar` and have all the variables be chars.

Comment: Im a she btw :) but i get what you mean, with the scanf("%d")

Answer (score 2):

You are only switching on `current_state` and not the input.

Comment: so i should be switching on x instead because thats where the input characters are to be held (read in from stdio)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the inner switch is a char, I believe you meant it to be on `x` and not `current_state`:

```
 switch(current_state){
  case 0: /*initial state*/
   switch(x){
   case'0':next_state=1; break;
   case'1':next_state=0; break;
   }
   break;
```